# Calculate the Euler-Mascheroni constant without the math module

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, mathematics, numerical-methods

The below code was written to generate [γ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), for educational purposes.

Single threaded, no functional zeroes required, no binary splitting(which can all be used to compute competitively like y-cruncher, that version in works).
Uses the Arithmetic Geometric Mean to calculate large logarithms quickly.
Uses decimal module for precision management.

I've computed 3000 digits in a few hours with it, and 200 in about a minute. I am happy calculating.

```
import decimal

D = decimal.Decimal

def agm(a, b):      #Arithmetic Geometric Mean
    a, b = D(a),D(b)
    for x in range(prec):
        a, b = (a + b) / 2, (a * b).sqrt()
    return a

def pi_agm():       #Pi via AGM and lemniscate
    a, b, t, p, pi, k = 1, D(2).sqrt()/2, 1/D(2), 2, 0, 0
    while 1:
        an    = (a + b) / 2
        b     = (a * b).sqrt()
        t    -= p * (a - an)**2
        a, p  = an, 2**(k+2)
        piold = pi
        pi    = (a + b) * (a + b) / (2*t)
        k    += 1
        if pi == piold:
            break
    return pi

def factorial(x):       #factorial fast loop
    x = int(x)
    factorial = D(1)
    for i in range(1, x+1):
        factorial *= i
    return factorial

def lntwo():        #Fast converging Ln 2
    logsum, logold, n = D(0), D(0), 0
    while 1:
        logold = logsum
        logsum += D(1/((D(961**n))*((2*n)+1)))
        n += 1
        if logsum == logold:
            logsum1 = (D(14)/D(31))*logsum
            break
    logsum, logold, n = D(0), D(0), 0
    while 1:
        logold = logsum
        logsum += D(1/((D(25921**n))*((2*n)+1)))
        n += 1
        if logsum == logold:
            logsum2 = (D(6)/D(161))*logsum
            break
    logsum, logold, n = D(0), D(0), 0
    while 1:
        logold = logsum
        logsum += D(1/((D(2401**n))*((2*n)+1)))
        n += 1
        if logsum == logold:
            logsum3 = (D(10)/D(49))*logsum
            break
    ln2 = logsum1 + logsum2 + logsum3
    return ln2

def lnagm(x):   #Natural log via AGM,
    try:
        if int(x) == 1:
            return 0
        if int(x) == 2:
            return lntwo()
    except:
        pass
    m = prec*2
    ln2 = lntwo()
    decimal.getcontext().prec = m
    pi = D(pi_agm())
    twoprec = D(2**(2-D(m)))/D(x)
    den = agm(1, twoprec)*2
    diff = m*ln2
    result = (D(pi/den) - D(diff))
    logr = D(str(result)[:m//2])
    decimal.getcontext().prec = prec
    return logr

def gamma():   #Compute Gamma from Digamma Expansion
    print('Computing Gamma!')
    k = D(prec/2)
    print('Calculating Logarithms...')
    lnk = lnagm(k)
    logsum = D(0)
    upper = int((12*k)+2)
    print('Summing...')
    for r in range(1, upper):
        logsum += D((D(-1)**D(r-1))*D(k**D(r+1)))/D(factorial(r-1)*D(r+1))
        if r%1000==0:
            print(str((D(r)/D(upper))*100)[:5], '% ; Sum 1 of 2')
    logsum1 = D(0)
    print('...')
    for r in range(1, upper):
        logsum1 += D((D(-1)**D(r-1))*(k**D(r+1)))/D(factorial(r-1)*D(D(r+1)**2))
        if r%1000==0:
            print(str((D(r)/D(upper))*100)[:5], '% ; Sum 2 of 2')
    twofac = D(2)**(-k)
    gammac = str(D(1)-(lnk*logsum)+logsum1+twofac)
    return D(gammac[:int(prec//6.66)])

#Calling Gamma
prec = int(input('Precision for Gamma: '))*8
decimal.getcontext().prec = prec
gam = gamma()
print(gam)
```

Comment: From purely mathematical point of view, you might be interested in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/129777/269624), which has a collection of different algorithms for this constant

Comment: That is excellent, thank you! I need to learn to write latex. The top answer is indeed the algorithm I wrote here :) I believe the only way I can go faster, is to use the algorithm involving a(log(a)-1)=1 and binary splitting.(ignoring its python).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Computation of `logsum` and `logsum1` in `gamma()` are suboptimal. You do costly operations of raising to power, and recompute factorial on each iteration (the latter invokes the quadratic time complexity BTW). Notice that in the \$\sum \dfrac{(-1)^{r-1} k^{r+1}}{(r+1)(r-1)!}\$ a consecutive term can be expressed via the previous one, as\$T_{r+1} = -k\dfrac{r+1}{(r+2)r} T_n\$. Instead of computing each term from scratch, use this recurrence, and enjoy a significant performance boost.

  Converting the summation into a [Horner schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) would likely improve the accuracy, that is to achieve the desired number of digits you'd need less number of terms.
- Tree loops in `lntwo` cry to become a function.

Comment: Thank you! I will implement everything you have said. However I believe using the recurrence and/or the Horner schema will prevent me from multi-threading in the future, just as an FYI to readers.